# Execute JS function after successful stripe payment

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I've decided to use the custom button code supplied by Stripe for accepting payment on a single product I sell. It looks like this:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Hire Bike (1 Day)</button>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: 'MY_KEY',
image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
locale: 'auto',
token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
}
});

document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
// Open Checkout with further options:
handler.open({
    name: 'Bike Company',
    description: '1 Day Bike Hire',
    currency: 'usd',
    amount: 25000
});
e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
handler.close();
});
</script>
```

While it does work (when I use my actual public API key of course), what I can't find a solution for is a way to execute some of my own JS when the payment is successful.

I can't find an answer in the documentation, so looking for suggestions from the SO community.

Comment: Stripe will run the token callback when the checkout is complete. So in your token callback, execute more code. Think **form -> token -> verify token -> done**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripe Execute Javascript On Form Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656659/stripe-execute-javascript-on-form-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run code in the token callback:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Hire Bike (1 Day)</button>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: 'MY_KEY',
image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
locale: 'auto',
token: function(token) {
    // DO STUFF HERE
    alert("Wahoo! You paid!")
}
});

document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
// Open Checkout with further options:
handler.open({
    name: 'Bike Company',
    description: '1 Day Bike Hire',
    currency: 'usd',
    amount: 25000
});
e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
handler.close();
});
</script>
```